# RDS Data Source Validation timeout Amazon QuickSight

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to connect an RDS database with postgreSQL engine to Amazon Quicksight in AWS. I have followed the documentation below:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rds-vpc-access.html
   this link is for Manually enabling access to an Amazon RDS instance in a VPC
2. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/quicksight-redshift-private-connection/
   this link is for connecting an amazon redshift database to quicksight (steps to link RDS are similar to those in the link.

After following these docs and trying to link RDS to quicksight, I was shown the following error:
[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4VFX.png)

Connection timed out. Check Your data source

Please provide suggestions as to how to solve this problem.

Comment: having the same issue after a year :). were you able to solve this problem?